# ASP.NET Core Dynamic Hiding and Showing Onchange

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to hide/show elements based on field value changes. For instance if I have the following:

```
<select id="SelectDiv">
    <option value="">-- choose --</option>
    <option value="Div1">Show Div1</option>
    <option value="Div2">Show Div2</option>
</select>
<div id="DivContainer">
    <div id="Div1" class="hidden">I'm Div1!</div>
    <div id="Div2" class="hidden">I'm Div2!</div>
</div>
```

and I select "Show Div1", I want to "refresh" the `DivContainer` and update the style classes based on the selection in `SelectDiv` dropdown.

Is this logic done server side or client side? The data will be bound to a model if that changes the way to approach this. I will need to do many of these types of operations throughout my app and I'm just trying to figure out the best way to structure things.

Comment: simplest way to do it by jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need do this on client side for quick response against user action with jquery.

```js
<script>
  $("#SelectDiv").change(function(){
    $("#DivContainer div").addClass("hidden");
    var selectedDiv =  $("#SelectDiv").val();
    
    $("#"+selectedDiv).removeClass("hidden");
  });
</script>
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="SelectDiv">
    <option value="">-- choose --</option>
    <option value="Div1">Show Div1</option>
    <option value="Div2">Show Div2</option>
</select>
<div id="DivContainer">
    <div id="Div1" class="hidden">I'm Div1!</div>
    <div id="Div2" class="hidden">I'm Div2!</div>
</div>
```